# Alert user using google places api

Tags: android, google-places-api

i currently have an android application that will find a users current location and shows places of interest within a specified radius on a map through Google places API. I am now looking for a way now to alert the user of these places when they come within the distance? e.g show a notification like "Point of interest is close by"

Comment: you just need to check for distance using lat/long of user and your fav. place  .. and put a condition check that if distance is around this then do that that .. else do that  ..

Comment: Yes so would it be that simple to return it to a user? e.g take their current coordinates and the places within that radius and just return a message in a dialog such as "Place is close by"?

Comment: Yeah ofcourse ... you just need to make a method and return some values in case of your's .. please check my answer ..

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Google's Geofencing API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html), I think it will be the best solution for you and also best solution battery-wise.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check for distance using lat/long of user and your fav. place .. and put a condition check that if distance is around this then do that that .. else do that .

Now just create a  method that will return your coordinate data ..

For Ex:--

```
public String getFinalCoordinates(){

// Perform action for lat and long .. and save it like string ..

your_lat_cum_long_data = your_data;

return your_lat_cum_long_data;
}
```

On later terms you can convert that String to double format like ..

```
double lat = Double.parseDouble(string) // It's some thing like  that .. 

// might be here I have done some syntax  error .. Please check same.
```

Else you are good to go ..

**EDIT**

you might be looking ahead to show notification when a ATM is nearby your location.

Now for this you need to put check like .. nearby ATM's, nearby restra, etc.

Now for each of defined above .. you need to put check like ..

```
if(places --> is equal to --> nearby ATM's)
{

//callNotificationMethod

}
else
{

// Keep pooling for places api ..

}
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: Ok i will give it a go. I am new to android and i just want to make it user friendly so after i return my results from within 5 miles of current location the user will gwt a notification telling them these places are closeby

Comment: Oh yeah .. you can do that .. also U need to request server to send  push using any web services .. Just call that web service that will let server know that it need to make a request to GCM for push ..

Comment: sorry i dont really know what you mean? i am using Google maps api and finding specific places within 5 miles of my current location. I am just looking for a simple notification to let the user know about places close to them?